# Ruby in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- CloudyScripts (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

On Ubuntu and Ruby 1.8.7, I installed CloudyScripts via:

```
gem install gem install CloudyScripts
```

When I try to execute this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'CloudyScripts'
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- CloudyScripts (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/copyami.rb:3
```

$ gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

amazon-ec2 (0.9.17)
CloudyScripts (1.9.40)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-ssh (2.2.1)
xml-simple (1.1.0)
```

The gem is installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems, the contents of which are

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2011-08-31 17:39 amazon-ec2-0.9.17
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2011-08-31 18:39 CloudyScripts-1.9.40
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2011-08-31 17:39 net-scp-1.0.4
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 2011-08-31 17:39 net-ssh-2.2.1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2011-08-31 17:39 xml-simple-1.1.0
```

And $LOAD_PATH is
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
    .

Why am I getting the load error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try

```
gem "CloudyScripts"
require "cloudyscripts"
```

Only the gem name is camelcased, but not the [ruby files](http://cloudyscripts.rubyforge.org/git?p=cloudyscripts.git;a=tree;f=lib;hb=HEAD) in it.

Comment: That worked.  I needed "require 'rubygems'"as the first line followed by your two lines, then everything was OK.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to run the rng(release notes generator command). The error is shown below.

/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- thor (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
        from ./rng:6:in `'

After lot of searching around I found the above post helpful. I just had to run 
C:\mydirectory>**gem install thor**

The rng command works perfectly now